# ModelForm not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have an app called **profile** which has de model *Profile(models.Model)*. Then, I have another app called **offer** with the model *Offer(models.Model)* and it has almost all the attributes of the Profile one, so I wanted to include a form with the attributes of profile in the offer. 
In the **forms.py** in the **offer** app, I have created:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from profile.models import Profile
from offer.models import Offer

class ProfileOfferForm(ModelForm):
    #extrafields
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('min_salary',)
```

And then in the **admin.py** (in the app **Offer** too) I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from offer.models import *
from offer.forms import *
# Register your models here.

from profile.models import Profile
@admin.register(Offer)
#admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin, ProfileForm)
class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        QuestionInline,
        AutomatismInline,
        CandidateInline
    ]
    form = ProfileOfferForm
```

And I get no errors, the only problem is that de fields of Profile don't appear in the administration in the section Offer. Am Ileaving something?
Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. You can't use a form that relates to a different model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget to register your custom Admin to your Model.

```
# At the bottom do something like this
admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
```